# Updating nodes on resizeable application in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Im writing an application in Java/JavaFX 8 which allows me to scan barcodes and display various informations linked to that barcode.

My application works as expected and all the node that needs to get updated after a scan are getting updated without a problem.

The initial height and width of the app are 900x600px (min-values). My problem starts when i resize my application (make it bigger). After resizing the app / maximize it the nodes (progressbars, buttons, textareas, etc) that needs to be updated after a scan are blocked by a white rectangle and thus wont show the updates node anymore.

Example images:

It should looks like this:
[node_ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQLd1.png)

But it looks like this:
[node_wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLMCW.png)

The interessting part is, that the node still works e.g. buttons are still clickable, it just wont show.

As soon as i resize the app to its original size the problem disappears. I can also start the application maximized and the problem ist not there as long as i dont start resizing the app.

I tried to find any similar problems that could help me find my error but i was unable to do so.

Is this a bug in JaxaFX or am i missing something on my end?

Comment: You're probably missing something, but that's impossible to tell without a [mcve]...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i need to see what i can do there without breaking company policy